# tcolorbox adds fragments of listing to list of listings

Tags: listings, lists, tcblisting

I'm writing a report due to tomorrow night but I have a problem that I can not resolve.
The code is the following, the problem is that in the list of listing appears also a fragment of the listing `test.vhd`.
I have already used this code without any problem but I realise now that also in the old reports if I change something (for example I remove one of the listings) this problem can appear. I don't understand why.
Thank you very much to anyone who will help me.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} 

\lstdefinelanguage{VHDL}{
   morekeywords={
     library, use, all, entity, is, port, variable, map, in, out, end, architecture, of, begin, and, generic, signal, if, then, else, generate, for, component, constant, process, to, downto, std_logic, std_logic_vector, ieee, std_logic_1164, std_logic_unsigned, numeric_std, rising_edge, type, case, when, others, natural, integer, unsigned, signed, array, to_integer
   },
   morecomment=[l]--
}
\lstdefinelanguage{ASM}{
   morekeywords={
    addui, jal, j, seqi, bnez, sw, lw, mult, jr
   },
   morecomment=[l]\;
}
\newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=chapter, list inside=listing]{VHDLlisting}[2][]{sharp corners, breakable, fonttitle=\bfseries, colframe=gray, listing only, listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny, commentstyle =\color{gray} \textit, language= VHDL, breaklines=true, showstringspaces=false, breakatwhitespace=false, tabsize=4, postbreak={\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}}}}, title=Listing \thetcbcounter: #2, #1, list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2}}
\newtcblisting[use counter from=VHDLlisting, number within=chapter, list inside=listing]{ASMlisting}[2][]{sharp corners, breakable, fonttitle=\bfseries, colframe=gray, listing only, listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny, commentstyle =\color{gray} \textit, language=ASM, breaklines=true, showstringspaces=false, breakatwhitespace=false, tabsize=4, postbreak={\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}}}}, title=Listing \thetcbcounter: #2, #1, list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2}}

\begin{document}

\tcblistof[\chapter*]{listing}{List of Listings}

\chapter{a chapter}
\begin{VHDLlisting}{test.vhd}
this is a listing
this is a listing
this is a listing
this is a listing
this is a listing
\end{VHDLlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `tcolorbox` parses a listing, it writes a temporary file `\jobname.listing` in which the current listing is stored for being read back in later on (under a changed catcode regime, I presume). Additionally, a file `\jobname.\tcb@lstof@VHDLlisting` is written, to which all the entries for the list of listings go.

In your document, as you specify `list inside=listing` in `\newtcblisting`, the file extension `\tcb@lstof@VHDLlisting` becomes `listing`, which clashes with the temporary output file for listings. The result is that different things go to the same file. On the next compilation run this file is included by `\tcblistof` and prints that random garbage left from one of the listings.

The fix is simply to choose another internal name for your list of listings, e.g. `mylisting`. The changes need to be applied to the `\newtcblisting` definition and the call of `\tcblistof`:

```
\newtcblisting[..., list inside=mylisting]{VHDLlisting}[2][]{ ... }

\tcblistof[\chapter*]{mylisting}{List of Listings}
```